# After upgrade from 64bit Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04 the laptop won't boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, 16.10, 17.04

My (64bit) system upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04. After the upgrade I restarted the system but the system will not boot. The only thing displaying on the screen is 'ad address'.

Any idea what went wrong and how to fix this? Boot-rescue? Download and re-install from CD?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/908868/edit) your question and add a picture of the screen?

Comment: Sorry no. The problem was sorted before you asked for the screenshot. Basically at the very beginning of boot-up the screen would be black with 'ad address' written on the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boot through live USB or CD and intall boot repair. for boot repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  after repairing restart. check if it works.

Comment: Finally got the boot repaired after the second try with Boot-Repair. I have no idea what went wrong, but from what I can sea by scanning the info, is that Grub found Windows 7 on my external drive which I had forgotten to remove before the upgrade. Somehow the MBR got corrupted, since on the 2nd run of Boot-Repair (after I removed the external harddrive) I could see it mentioning 'repairing MBR'. After this run the laptop finally booted. The link to the first boot-repair info is: http://paste2.org/1GJ1LgCG.